# x length of string in python

Tags: python, string

Hi I want to create app that will work like this:
string from file for example:

```
AAAAa aaaaa
bb bbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccc
```

will be wrapped by x when x will be max length of the line so for x = 10 it will look like

```
AAAAa aaaa
aabb bbbbb   
....
```

I have tried this code but it do not work

```
def length(x):
    return x
t = open("text.txt", "r")
x = int(input("Enter length: \n"))
length(x)
for line in t:
     print(line.strip())
     if int(len(line) >= length(x)):
          print("\n")
t.close()
```

This code is doing something else, can you help me please ? :)

Comment: None of your output lines exist in your input. I don't understand your question.

Comment: You are not sorting, you are wrapping, but your output doesn't match your description; your lines are not length 10, and your character counts don't match.

Comment: Okay so i am wrapping text. For example first line have 25 chars but i want output to divide it into 10 char line 10 char line and 5 char line. If x= 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they want to take the text file and iterate through each character until X is reached then start a new line continuing to print the text until x is reached again.

this needs modification and is untested

```
def textiterator(xinput):
    counter = 0
    transformedtext = ''
    textfromfile = ''
    textfile = open('youroriginaltextfile.txt', 'r')

    for eachline in textfile:
            textfromfile = textfromfile + eachline

    while counter <= len(textfromfile):

        if counter not equal to % of xinput: ##modulus operator needs to be added for multiple of xinput
            transformedtext = transformedtext + textfromfile[counter]
            counter = counter + 1

        else:
            transformedtext = transformedtext + '\n'


    return transformedtext
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This created infinite loop, but thanks for algorithm, i will try to make it works

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> t='''AAAAa aaaaa
bb bbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccc'''
>>> x = int(raw_input("Enter length: "))
>>> print '\n'.join(t.replace('\n', '')[i:i+x] for i in range(0, len(x), x))
AAAAa aaaa
abb bbbbbb
bbbbbbbccc
cccccccccc
```

so:

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
    t = f.read()
x = int(input("Enter length: \n"))
print '\n'.join(t.replace('\n', '')[i:i+x] for i in range(0, len(x), x))
close t
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
def in_groups(seq, n):
    # see http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes
    return zip(*[iter(seq)] * n)

l = int(raw_input("Enter length: "))
with open("text.txt") as f:
    contents = f.read()
print '\n'.join(''.join(t) for t in in_groups(contents.replace('\n', ''), l))
```